# Flutter Inappwebview Crashes/Freezes when App resumes from background

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, flutter-inappwebview

Inappwebview freezes when the app is resumed from background on android 10+ and the app crashes on Android version less than 10. I've tried downgrading Flutter to version 2.2.0 and even tried running the code example [here](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/in-app-webview/basic-usage/) but still same issue.

Messages in run output:

```
I/FirebaseApp(10672): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
E/LB      (10672): fail to open file: No such file or directory
D/EgretLoader(10672): EgretLoader(Context context)
D/EgretLoader(10672): The context is not activity
W/nology.jumiane(10672): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/nology.jumiane(10672): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/nology.jumiane(10672): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/nology.jumiane(10672): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/cr_media(10672): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/ContentCatcher(10672): Failed to notify a WebView
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(kef.technology.jumianet)
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
W/FlutterJNI(10672): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
I/ResourceExtractor(10672): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-6-1655787362773
W/FlutterJNI(10672): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(10672): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
I/FLTFireBGExecutor(10672): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling]
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 4 lines
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/FLTFireMsgService(10672): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
V/MiuiFrameworkFactory(10672): get AllImpl object = android.common.MiuiFrameworkFactoryImpl@7251d6
W/MirrorManager(10672): this model don't Support
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 15 lines
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 11 lines
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 1 line
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 12 lines
E/FrameEvents(10672): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : requestUpdateInfo(kef.technology.jumianet)
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : Initiate binding to the service.
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.installservice.DevTriggeredUpdateService})
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : linkToDeath
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] OnRequestInstallCallback : onRequestInfo
I/PlayCore(10672): UID: [10479]  PID: [10672] AppUpdateService : Unbind from service.
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/RenderInspector(10672): QueueBuffer time out on kef.technology.jumianet/kef.technology.jumianet.MainActivity, count=5, avg=12 ms, max=25 ms.
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/RenderInspector(10672): DequeueBuffer time out on kef.technology.jumianet/kef.technology.jumianet.MainActivity, count=1, avg=16 ms, max=16 ms.
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 1 line
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 1 line
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 6 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 4 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 4 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 5 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 15 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 1 line
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 12 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 29 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 6 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 5 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 1 line
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 9 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 5 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 5 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 9 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 5 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 38 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 10 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 21 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 21 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 19 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/JavaBinder(10672): BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: com.google.android.play.core.internal.zzai
I/BpBinder(10672): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
W/JavaBinder(10672): BinderProxy is being destroyed but the application did not call unlinkToDeath to unlink all of its death recipients beforehand.  Releasing leaked death recipient: com.google.android.play.core.internal.zzai
I/BpBinder(10672): onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients: <uncached descriptor>
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 2 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 7 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 4 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 4 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 3 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
I/chatty  (10672): uid=10479(kef.technology.jumianet) RenderThread identical 14 lines
W/OpenGLRenderer(10672): The surface had destroyed before draw
```

It shows **The surface had destroyed before draw** everytime I scroll the page after it freezes

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed after i upgraded to the latest version of Flutter Sdk.

You can run;

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issues on github, you can try to upgrade the flutter version to 2.10.5 or higher